# AccessViolationException in SilverLight KeyDown Handler

Tags: c#, silverlight

In a KeyDown event I have:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
    if (HtmlPage.Window.Confirm("r u sure?"))
    {
        //Do stuff....
    }
}
```

And I am getting this error "
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." @Confirm?

EDIT: workaround shown below and the line it was throwing the error on was `.Window.Confirm`

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            if (HtmlPage.Window.Confirm("r u sure?"))
            {
                //Do stuff....
            }
        }
    });
```

Anyone know a quick solution.

Comment: Can you isolate the specific line that's throwing this exception? Is it one of the `if()` conditions, or is it in the `//Do stuff`?

Comment: I don't get any error, using your exact example. When do you get the error before the confirm box appears, after clicking a button in the confirm box? What browser?

Comment: Whence comes that workaround? Are you trying to popup a confirm dialog outside of the UI thread, or something?

Comment: I find the type of exception thrown surprising. IMO this exception should only occur if you have buggy native or unsafe code. So it should never occur in(in browser) silverlight programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        if (HtmlPage.Window.Confirm("r u sure?"))
        {
            //Do stuff....
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty good explanation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190259%28VS.95%29.aspx). This surfaces commonly when a `BackgroundWorker` thread is spun up and then the attempt to access a `UIElement` takes place, such as a Button, you would also get an `AccessViolationException` at that point.

Comment: @gmcalab Note my answer @ 18mins, note the edit @ 16mins which is when the Dispatcher reference surfaced...no Echo...

Comment: thanks that what I figured out too. Can you briefly explain why do we have to do this?

Comment: Actually, the edit that was done 2 minutes prior was John Saunders edit not the OP's edit. Echo.

Comment: @gmcalab My answer was @ 17:07:26 and the revision by the OP was @ 17:06:56 with a net difference of 30 seconds. I'll make certain this never happens again...I'm so ashamed...yawn...